# converting 5 temperatures from fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: c, scanf, temperature

Every day, a weather station receives 5 temperatures expressed in degree Fahrenheit.  Write a program to accept temperature in Fahrenheit, convert it to Celsius and display the converted temperature on the screen. After 5 temperatures, the message ‘All temperatures processed’ should be displayed on the screen

My answer is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int fah, cel;
  printf("\nEnter 5 temperatures in Fahrenheit: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &fah);
  do
  { 
    cel=(fah-32)*(5/9);
    printf("\n These temperatures converted to Celsius are: %d \n", cel);
  }
  while(fah);
}
```

Comment: WHERE DID I GO WRONG ? You didn't post precisely what your problem is ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? (apart from the infinite loop)

Comment: Well, that program, apart from being buggy, doesn't do what is asked for. You were asked to terminate after 5 temperatures, not after a zero input, and you were asked to print a status message.

Comment: This is already your third homework in a row, that you try to get solved on SO. This site is to answer concrete technical questions, not to review your homework. Please stop it. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &fah);
```

You used 5 `%d` in the conversion specifier, but only one variable.

```
cel=(fah-32)*(5/9);
```

Here, you used integer division, change the type of the variables to `double` and `5/9` to `5.0/9`

Comment: Can i get the direct solution?? mine is totally messed up i know, but im confused and i tried maybe if u tell me ill be able to understand

Comment: @gadoora - read the good answers and work at it. It's the only way to learn this stuff well, honest!  Hint - break up your problem - get it to work with one value first, then think about extending it to five.

Comment: @gadoora Martin's right, it's better that you tried it yourself step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take this one by one -

- `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &fah);` : You want to scan five values while you are using only one `%d`. What about the other four values ? You should use an array of 5 values.
- `cel=(fah-32)*(5/9);` : You are dividing 5 by 9, both of which are integers. The result of dividing an integer by another, a/b, where a < b is 0. Hence `cel` will always be 0. You have to cast one of the integers to a float/double.
- If you do use an array, you need to loop over all elements of the array to process them.

I am purposely not providing a direct solution to all these. I suggest you look up on these things and understand them, since they are very basic for programming in C.

Answer (score 1):

You're working in integers --> 5/9 is converted to integer 0 thus the result will also equal to 0. You need to work with `float`/`double` types or change your calculation to minimize such rounding errors, e.g. something like this: `cel=(5*(fah-32))/9;` - here the multiplication is done first and division after that.